# What proof do we have that visual attraction to other humans is a natural biological trait?

Tags: sexuality

There's [another question answered](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/is-there-a-biological-basis-to-physical-attraction) that relates to this, but the sources don't show enough evidence of how it is a natural biological trait that we're born with.

Even though there's evidence that culture influences some of our behaviors on visual attraction towards other people, is there any evidence this stems from something that is a natural biological trait?

Comment: I think your question might fit on a sister stack, but you need to better define "natural biological trait". You mean if it is 'pre-programmed' in our brains? If it is genetic? What are you looking for? Secondly, and not less importantly, what do you mean by visual attraction? What kind of outcome measure would you use for that?